# How to convert ints to strings in SML recursively?

Tags: recursion, sml

I made a very small program which takes an int and converts it into string in SML:

```
fun int2str i =
  if i < 0 then "~" ^ Int.toString (~i) 
  else Int.toString i;


int2str(~1234) --> "~1234"
int2str(1234)  --> "1234"
```

I have been struggling immensely to accomplish this in a recursive way. Any help? Additionally, I had to take a string and convert it into an int which I finished through stackOverflow help in general, but the '~' screws everything up as well; however this was able to be finished recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you need to do this recursively since calling `Int.toString` on any int will produce the desired result (even if it's negative) but you can also do:

```
fun helper 0 = "" | helper n = helper (Int.div(n, 10)) ^ Int.toString (Int.mod (n, 10));

fun int2str n = if n < 0 then "~" ^ helper(~n) else if n = 0 then "0" else helper(n);
```

Modding by 10 will get the last digit and integer dividing by 10 will cut off the last digit so this should get you your desired results in a recursive manner.